# how find value of $a$ in polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image] 
i tried to get value of a but can't factor this equation  "ii"

${x^3+ax^2-2=0  }$   "i"

${x(x^2+ax-2)=0}$   "ii"

are this step are right ? i can't continue my steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2. step is not right, you can check this by multiplying out: $$x(x^2+ax-2)=x^3+ax^2-2x$$

If $-1$ is a zero, then (replacing $x$ with $-1$)$$(-1)^3+a(-1)^2-1=0$$

Can you take it from here? Also, is your polynomial $x^3+ax^2-1$ and not $x^3+ax^2-2$?

Answer (score 1):

Plug in $x=-1$ and solve for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Plug in ${x=−1}$

${-1^3 + a(-1)^2 -1 = 0}$          
 
${-1 + a - 1 = 0 } $      
${ 2 = a }$